# Strange Ascii character in mySQL. Need a query to delete it

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work out how to remove the character Â from a mySQL database. It has been converted for me by someone else who hasn't done a great job.

table is ps_product_lang

fields are description AND description_short

I think my query should be

update ps_product_lang set description = replace(description, ‘Â’, ‘’)

**But what should I put in where the Â is?** When I try to do a search it finds every 'a'.

ASCII code 182 = Â ( Letter A with circumflex accent or A-circumflex )
( HTML entity = Â )

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean?You search for  Â and it finds just plain a?

Comment: There's no such things as "ASCII code 182" - ASCII stops at 127 (or possibly 126, depending on the exact definition you're using). There are various "extended ASCII" (urgh) encodings which are compatible with ASCII but which have different meanings for values 128-255. I suspect you mean one of those.

Comment: Isn't this just a remnant of UTF-8? I'd like to see some data samples (byte sequences). Another thing to ask is, what was actually converted? If the strings weren't, they're maybe just misinterpreted now, where switching the encoding to UTF-8 gives a hint.

Answer (score 2):

CHAR(182) matches the character that is integer code 182.

So you can do this:

```
update ps_product_lang set description = replace(description, CHAR(182), '')
```

Documentation for CHAR() [is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char)

Comment: @Mihai, yes it selects all a's

Comment: It did help and it didn't. I wasn't sure about CHAR(182) being the right number. I think I may have looked in the wrong place.

Comment: Where I am at now is by using
SELECT * 
FROM  `ps_product_lang` 
WHERE LENGTH(  `description` ) != CHAR_LENGTH(  `description` ) 
I can see I have 1417 fields with the odd A. 

So now I am trying to work out how to replace them all with nothing, ie delete them. And advice?

Comment: I think you can use this both for the where and to update the fields: WHERE description <> CONVERT(description USING ASCII)